# Logstash in Docker - Combine 2 events into 1 event

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am running ElasticStack in Docker via their official images; however, I'm currently receiving the following error message when I attempt to use the Logstash - aggregate plugin to combine events that have the same RequestID:

> Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Couldn't find any filter plugin named 'aggregate'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the aggregate filter plugin resulted in this error: Problems loading the requested plugin named aggregate of type filter. Error: NameError NameError"}

That said, I'm also not 100% sure how to use the Logstash - aggregate plugin to combine the following sample events into one event:

```
{
    "@t": "2017-10-16T20:21:35.0531946Z",
    "@m": "HTTP GET Request: \"https://myapi.com/?format=json&trackid=385728443\"",
    "@i": "29b30dc6",
    "Url": "https://myapi.com/?format=json&trackid=385728443",
    "SourceContext": "OpenAPIClient.Client",
    "ActionId": "fd683cc6-9e59-427f-a9f4-7855663f3568",
    "ActionName": "Web.Controllers.API.TrackController.TrackRadioLocationGetAsync (Web)",
    "RequestId": "0HL8KO13F8US6:0000000E",
    "RequestPath": "/api/track/radiourl/385728443"
}
{
    "@t": "2017-10-16T20:21:35.0882617Z",
    "@m": "HTTP GET Response: LocationAPIResponse { Location: \"http://sample.com/file/385728443/\", Error: null, Success: True }",
    "@i": "84f6b72b",
    "Response":
    {
        "Location": "http://sample.com/file/385728443/",
        "Error": null,
        "Success": true,
        "$type": "LocationAPIResponse"
    },
    "SourceContext": "OpenAPIClient.Client",
    "ActionId": "fd683cc6-9e59-427f-a9f4-7855663f3568",
    "ActionName": "Web.Controllers.API.TrackController.TrackRadioLocationGetAsync (Web)",
    "RequestId": "0HL8KO13F8US6:0000000E",
    "RequestPath": "/api/track/radiourl/385728443"
}
```

**Could someone please guide me on how to correctly combine these events and if aggregate is the correct plugin, why the built-in plugin doesn't seem to be a part of the Logstash Docker image?**

docker-compose.yml contents:

```
 version: '3'
 services:
   elasticsearch:
     image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.3
     container_name: elasticsearch
     environment:
       - discovery.type=single-node
       - xpack.security.enabled=false
     ports:
       - 9200:9200
     restart: always
   logstash:
     image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3
     container_name: logstash
     environment:
       - xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
     depends_on:
       - elasticsearch
     ports:
       - 10000:10000
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
   kibana:
     image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.6.3
     container_name: kibana
     environment:
       - xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url=http://elasticsearch:9200
     depends_on:
       - elasticsearch
     ports:
       - 5601:5601
     restart: always
```

logstash/pipeline/empstore.conf contents:

```
 input {
     http {
         id => "empstore_http"
         port => 10000
         codec => "json"
     }
 }

 output {
     elasticsearch {
         hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
         id => "empstore_elasticsearch"
         index => "empstore-openapi"
     }
 }

 filter {
     mutate {
         rename => { "RequestId" => "RequestID" }
     }

    aggregate {
         task_id => "%{RequestID}"
         code => ""
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the code in your filter  is a required setting.

Example of code:

- Request_END :

  code => "map['sql_duration'] += event.get('duration')"
- Request_START:

  code => "map['sql_duration'] = 0"
- Request:

  code => "map['sql_duration'] += event.get('duration')"

Comment: So there is no way to simply combine the existing fields of the two events without going through the overhead of determining which one is the Request and which one is the Response?

Comment: look here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example4

Comment: code => "
         map['country_name'] = event.get('country_name')
         map['towns'] ||= []
         map['towns'] << {'town_name' => event.get('town_name')}
         event.cancel()
       "

Comment: I ended up deciding that it was much easier to modify the app emitting the events to combine them than it was to figure out how to install / use the aggregate plugin correctly especially since I can't ensure that events won't arrived interlaced once the app is deployed across several machines.

Comment: it's not bad as a solution! Good!